# How to check if any of my app's users are banned by Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I believe my question this time is simple. Let say I have a webpage, which lets user to link theirs account with account on my webpage. Let say at some point facebook bans invalid account  (assume some of them were bots and spiders), is there a way to check which and if any of my users got banned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deactivated accounts won't work with the API , so a call to `/USER_ID` will return `false`

**Update**: This message was updated recently (Q3 2012) to be a valid exception - it now returns a real exception for all privacy failures and / or accessing nonexistent or deleted content

```
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request.",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100

}
```

Comment: But does it means that I will have to periodically check all my users?  Sounds quite heavy.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to check if an ID still represents a valid Facebook user - you'll be able to mark anyone actively using the app as 'valid', it's only the people not still using your app you'd need to check and even then only when you were going to use their data for something, no?

Comment: But if you assume that user is more reliable when he/she has active facebook account and if he/she doesn't, that person will loose some or even full access to your website (for example you want to remove all items sold by bots/spammers/scammers that were identified by facebook).

Comment: But they won't be able to continue logging in to the site without their Facebook profile if your login system works like most sites - if you allow logins via your own system too, you could check their facebook account is still active at various points like login, create ad, ad renewal, etc

Comment: That's right, I can block their log in attempt but I cannot remove items on my e-shop that they are selling or profiles on my dating service. Unless they try to log in which may or may not happen.